# JHipster new version creates 500 server error "failed to map to source...to class" using Elasticsearch

Tags: jhipster

Generated a new JHipster application using v5.3.0 with Elasticsearch

I'm using the same JDL that I used with the previous version of JHipster which worked successfully but could not deploy.

I generate successful. No errors. No problems.

When I open the application and try CRUD with my entities...works normally.

For one of my entities, the Elasticsearch search returns a 500 server error.

Again, this is just after generating the application. I haven't changed anything.

This JDL worked in the last version. The failing entity works fine for all CRUD operations...just throws the error when doing a search. All the other entities work fine doing a search.

The JSON response mentions "failed to map to source...to class".

The generator created that mapping without errors. Why would it being failing during a search?

Why do the other entities work OK?

Any ideas? Anybody else have problems?

Comment: When I search for something that is not in the database, no error. Only if it tries to return a line that is in the database.

Comment: I also get the following occasional error... `Http failure response for http://localhost:9000/api/_search/jobs?page=-1&query=FL&size=20&sort=id,asc: 504 Gateway Timeout`

Comment: `Error occured while trying to proxy to: localhost:9060/api/employers`

Comment: I don't think the last two errors are related to the mapping problem.

Comment: Got it. Date field.

The new release notes say the following:

More user friendly Angular’s datepicker for local dates #7699

Does the new date picker break Elasticsearch applications?

If I add a line without a date, no error. Only when I search for a line that contains a date that is filled in do I get the error.

But if I fill in the date manually without the date picker I still get the error.

Something in the new version break date fields in Elasticsearch JHipster applications?

Comment: I removed my date fields using the sub generator and now work as expected. No errors. Not using date fields is going to be a problem but works for now at least.

Comment: This is a bug in the generator.  Please open an issue https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/new/choose

Comment: Done. Thank you for what you do.

Answer (score 1):

Bug in JHipster 5.3.0 generator.

See https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/8222